# Django Mass Update/Insert Performance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-database

I'm receiving financial data for approximately 5000 instruments every 5 seconds, and need to update the respective entries in the database.  The model looks as follows:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    market = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    ask = models.FloatField()
    bid = models.FloatField()
    lastUpdate = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
```

What needs to happen is the following:

- After new financial data is received, check if an entry exists in the
  database.
- If the entry exists, update the ask, bid and lastUpdate fields
- If the entry does not exist, create a new entry

My code looks as follows:

```
bi_markets = []
for item in dbMarkets:
    eItem = Market.objects.filter(exchange=item.exchange,market=item.market)
    if len(eItem) > 0:
        eItem.update(ask=item.ask,bid=item.bid)
    else:
        bi_markets.append(item)

#Bulk insert items that does not exist
Market.objects.bulk_create(bi_markets)
```

However executing this takes way too long.  Approximately 30 seconds.  I need to reduce the time down to 1 second.  I know this can be done as I do the same wth custom SQL code in .NET in under 100ms.  Any idea how to improve the performance in Django?

Comment: Try adding `db_index=True` for `market` & `exchange` fields.

Comment: why not use `exists = Model.objects.filter(category='django').exists()` will help to reduce one check and try to fetch dbmatrkets using value.i mean like this `dbmarkets = Model.objects.value('value1','value2')`.This willl reduce your query time.

Comment: adding indexes did not increase performance

Comment: using exists() will add an additional layer of running time as 99.9% of the items will exist in the table

Comment: No it won't. It will be a (slight) optimisation over `len()` which calls `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s this kind of performance you’re going for, I don’t see why you wouldn’t just break out into raw SQL. Bulk creating things that don’t exist yet sounds like the advanced SQL querying that Django isn’t really made for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

You can also do (sorry on mobile):

```
bi_markets = []
for item in dbMarkets:
  rows = Market.objects.filter(exchange=item.exchange, market=item.market).update(ask=item.ask, bid=item.bid)
  if rows == 0:
    bi_markets.append(item)

Market.objects.bulk_create(bi_markets)
```

Maybe that combination will generate some better SQL and it sidesteps the `exists()` call as well (`update` returns how many rows it changed).

Comment: Thanks.  The problem is not bulk inserting.  It is checking if the items exists and updating it.  If I delete all items and bulk insert it is fast enough, but the problem is the PK obviously changes every time.  Will need 'bulk update' functionality where a different update for each item can be given

Comment: I expanded it and maybe this'll perform? At least it is much tidier.

Answer (score -3):

I've decided to split the update and create functionality.  The create only happens when the app starts, from there on I do updates using custom SQL script.  See below.  Working great.

```
updateQ = []
updateQ.append("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")

for dbItem in dbMarkets:
    eItem = tickers[dbItem.market]
    qStr = "UPDATE app_market SET ask = " + str(eItem['ask']) + ",bid = " + str(eItem['bid']) + " WHERE exchange_id = " + str(e.dbExchange.pk) + " AND market = " + '"' + dbItem.market + '";'
    updateQ.append(qStr)

updateQ.append("COMMIT;")

updateQFinal  = ''.join(map(str, updateQ))

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.executescript(updateQFinal)
```

Comment: Is this for real? At least read through the Django documentation on raw SQL and how they use %s to protect against injection attacks.