# Conditional bulk updates: Django bulk_update or temporary table + sql

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, join

Thanks for reading my question! I use django (3.0.8) with postgres 12. Below is a simplified model for `Inventory`. There are about 1M records.

```py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    item_id = models.LargeIntegerField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Every hour we receive new `snapshots` of one Account through REST API, e.g. `acc_0`. That contains a full list of items (~100k records), not deltas. I wanted to apply 3 actions:

1. Set `amount=0 where account==acc_0` if `item_id` not in the new `snapshots`.
2. Set `amount=snapshot['amount'] where account==acc_0` if `item_id` in the new `snapshots`.
3. Create new items if `snapshot['item_id']` not in `Inventory.item_id`

Each time, most items already exist in DB and their amount is unchanged, i.e. the real delta is quite small (100-1k records).

What I'm doing now seems not very efficient:

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    new_items = {}
    update_items = {}
    Inventory.objects.filters(account=acc_0).update(amount=0)
    for snapshot in snapshots:
        item_id = snapshot['item_id']
        results = Inventory.objects.filter(item_id=item_id)
        if len(results) == 0:
            new_items[item_id] = Inventory(...)
        else:
            item = result[0]
            item.amount = snapshot['amount']
            update_items[item_id] = item
    Inventory.objects.bulk_create(new_items.values())
    Inventory.objects.bulk_update(update_items.values(), ['amount'])
```

I was wondering should I upload the snapshot to a temporary table and use UPDATE SET CASE JOIN, INSERT INTO SELECT NOT EXISTS or even better there is a more pythonic way.

There is one similar question: [Django Mass Update/Insert Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112605/django-mass-update-insert-performance) but it's also open.

Answer (score 0):

As you have three questions, I will answer your question in 3 separate parts. I'm no expert on Postgres, but I can tell you the most *convenient* way of solving your problem using Django.

I won't say efficient as I haven't handled large datasets, but seeing as they're all Django-default functions, I will expect them to perform fairly well.

1 and 2: I will assume that your `account` objects are already sorted in terms of their id. If they are sorted, a **binary search** algorithm will do the trick (only equal to linear search at its worse case, best at log(N) where N is the time for linear search). Once you find the item, do whatever you need to. If they are not sorted, don't bother yourself and just go for a *standard linear search*.

3: You either get the object, or you create one. Django's [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) is exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, `account` is indexed. `Inventory.objects.filters().update() and bulk_*()` are not so bad. The slowest part seems to be:
`for snapshot in snapshots:
        results = Inventory.objects.filter(item_id=item_id)
`

Comment: where is `snapshot` in the second line?

Comment: It's retrieved every hour from a REST API.

Comment: First of all, you might want to consider using python's list comprehension, which optimizes the speed, so it will look sth like `results = [Inventory.objects.filter(item_id=snapshot['item_id']) for snapsnot in snapshots]`. Besides, I'm suspicious whether the if-else statement should belong inside the for look